# Why is it not possible to connect Android directly with Oracle

Tags: android, oracle, jdbc, driver, database-connectivity

While trying to build a direct connection between an Android app and the Oracle database, i have gone through a lot of posts and tutorials saying it`s not possible. However, it was never clearly mentioned why it is not possible. So, what is the reason?

Comment: Independent of being possible or not, it is something you don't really want to do.

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android

Comment: @MorrisonChang thank you!